# Using ValueProvider<Long> with FixedWindows and Duration

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Moving toward Apache Beam 2.x, I want to use templates as much as possible, and ValueProvider accordingly.

In my logic, I am using a FixedWindow, but the duration is flexible, so I rather get it from a ValueProvider.

The problem is that FixedWindows.of() only get Duration, and I failed to find a simple way to grab a ValueProvider and make a duration out of it.

Please advise,
Shushu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this question has a simple answer: this is currently not supported. Feel free to [file a JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM) - it seems like a reasonable request.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this exact issue today but with SlidingWindows, we just wrote our own windowing function with a new param that was a ValueProvider instead (similar to https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/3358/files) and this seems to work.